# TFS Security and Documents Folder

Tags: security, sharepoint, tfs

I'm getting an issue with TFS where the documents folder is marked with a red cross.  As far as I can tell, this seems to be a security issue, however, I am set-up as project admin on the relevant projects.

I’ve come to the conclusion that it’s a security issue from running the TFS Project Admin tool (available [here](http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/releases/view/24283)).  When I run this, it tells me that I don’t have sufficient access rights to open the project.  I’ve checked, and I’m not included in any groups that are denied access.

Please can anyone shed any light as to why I may not have sufficient access to these projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this.  The security for SharePoint is set-up independently, and it's this that controls the access to the Documents folder